# open the youtube link thorugh my application without webview

Tags: iphone

I am using this code so that youtube video will display without webview

```
-(IBAction) trailor {

    //declaring path to file and stuff...

    NSString *urlAddress = self.Trailor;//@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZXcWK0tZjc&feature=related";

    NSLog(@"url %@",urlAddress);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress]; 



    MPMoviePlayerViewController *playerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url   ];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:[playerViewController moviePlayer]];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:[playerViewController moviePlayer]];      

    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [playerViewController moviePlayer];
    [self.view addSubview:playerViewController.view];
    player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    player.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    [player setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
} 


- (void)moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:moviePlayer];

    [moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
    //[self.view setHidden:NO];


    [moviePlayer release];  
}
```

but there is no any reponse from this code, when I run this code thorugh a button.. it will [image] it will display me only this screen and nothing else.

I want to open youtube link thorugh my app without using webview how can I do it

any sample code? or tutorial you have then plz share it to me

Comment: can you give me the answer of the question that I asked with you

Answer (score 0):

There are similar (if not same ) questions out there.
youtube donot give direct access to video (which MPMoviePlayerViewController expects). hence it cant play the youtube videos directly (using initWithContentURL).

The only method is to play Youtube videos in your app is through UIWebView. see 
[How to Play Youtube video in webview in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962729/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-webview-in-iphone) to get better idea on how to.