# How to Play Youtube video in webview in iphone?

Tags: iphone

how to remove default done button of MPMovieController in iphone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

- http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/audio-video/how-to-play-youtube-videos-within-an-application
- http://apiblog.youtube.com/2009/02/youtube-apis-iphone-cool-mobile-apps.html

Answer (score 1):

You can't add it directly to the `MPMoviePlayerController`'s view -- that's a private view and it can't be accessible.

If you want to add buttons, you need to create a transparent window over the top of everything and add the buttons to that.

Apple's [MoviePlayer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007798) sample shows how to do this.